# How do I make my discord music bot have a queue for music?

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm making a Discord bot that plays music, I've got it working but it only has the ability to play a song, and when you link the bot a different song instead of waiting for the first song to end, it will just cancel the first song and go straight to the second one. I'm using discord.js, and I have put my code into GitHub. Here is my code: `

```
if(command === '!music') {
    var link = arg1
    console.log(link)
    const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
    const streamOptions = { seek: 0, volume: 1 };
    const broadcast = bot.createVoiceBroadcast();

    if(link === undefined) {
        bot.guilds.get(guildid).channels.get(generalchan).send("You need to put a link after !music to put a song in the queue")
    } else {
        if (message.member.voiceChannel) {
            message.member.voiceChannel.join()
              .then(connection => { // Connection is an instance of VoiceConnection
                message.reply('SONG : ' + link);
                const streamOptions = { seek: 0, volume: arg2/100, filter : "audioonly" };
                connection.playStream(ytdl(link), streamOptions);
            })
        } else {
            message.reply("You need to be in a voice channel for me to join")
        }
    }
}'
```

I would also like help on a vote skip feature where people can vote to skip a song that is currently playing and go to the next song.

Answer (score 1):

You need to queue your songs.

This bot I am going to show you also works on multiple servers without interrupting channels that are already using this function.

Here you are telling him, amongst other things, to play the next song in queue:

```
var servers = {};

function play(connection, message) {
    var server = servers[message.guild.id];

    server.dispatcher = connection.playStream(YTDL(server.queue[0], { filter: 
    "audioonly" }));

    server.dispatcher.setVolume(0.2);

    server.queue.shift();

    server.dispatcher.on("end", function () {

    if (server.queue[0]) play(connection, message);
    else connection.disconnect();

});

}
```

The .server you'll need if you want to make this work on more servers at the same time.

I also have the switch:

```
switch (args[0]) {
 case "play":
        if (!args[1]) {
            message.reply("Please provide a link")
            return;
        }
        if (!message.member.voiceChannel) {
            message.channel.send("You must be in a voice channel!")
            return;
        }
        if (!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
            queue: []
        }
        var server = servers[message.guild.id];

        server.queue.push(args[1]);

        if (!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(function (connection) {
                play(connection, message);
        });
        break;
 case "skip":
        var server = servers[message.guild.id];

        if (server.dispatcher) server.dispatcher.end();
        break;

 case "stop":
        var server = servers[message.guild.id];

        if (message.guild.voiceConnection) message.guild.voiceConnection.disconnect();
        break;
}
```

And up there I ask the content of the message.

In the "play" section I also ask if a link has been given with the if args[1]

In the "skip" section I force the dispatcher to end the song and start the next one that is in the queue.

In the "stop" section the bot leaves the voicechannel